# Why does this simple C program segfault?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

This very simple C code compiles, and runs, but it segfaults when it ends. I cannot figure out why.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/statfs.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

        struct statfs sf;

        if (stat(argv[1], &sf) == 0 ) {
                printf( "Statfs succeeded!\n");
                printf("\tFs type:\t %#lx\n", sf.f_type);
                printf("\tTotal blocks:\t %lu\n", sf.f_blocks);
                printf("\tFree blocks:\t %lu\n", sf.f_bavail);
                printf("\tinodes:\t %lu\n", sf.f_files);
        } else {
                printf("Statfs failed!\n");
                return 1;
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Compile and run:

```
[root@dadam-4 ~]# gcc statfs-test.c -o statfs-test
[root@dadam-4 ~]# ./statfs-test /dev/sda1
Statfs succeeded!
    Fs type:     0x5
    Total blocks:    1
    Free blocks:     6
    inodes:  2049
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

It think the problem has to do with the statfs struct not being freed, but I'm not sure. There's no segfault if I run it for the failure case.

Comment: It should be `struct stat` and not `struct statfs` i think.

Comment: @AlexFarber: `stat` uses `struct stat`, `statfs` uses `struct statfs`, see [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/statfs.2.html)

Comment: @MOehm: right, but the code in the question uses `stat` with `struct statfs`

Comment: @n.m. Impressive, very nice.

Comment: @AlexFarber: Okay, didn't really see that. Good catch, then. (Although I think it's the other way round: The user wants to call `fsstat`.)

Comment: @Igor If I'm being nice, it's a bug.

Comment: @n.m. You are not. Your answer was impressive. Very nice.

Comment: I think this site needs another closing option. "This question appears to be off-topic because the problem results from not paying attention to compiler warnings", or something like that.

Comment: @MOehm doh! Thanks! I'd originally used stat, and intended to switch to statfs. Thanks for the eyes!

Comment: @AdamDrew: Don't thank my eyes, thank Alex's eyes. :-)

Comment: @n.m. there was the (dreaded) "no minimal understanding" close reason. The team has removed that because it was easy to take it as being mean.

Comment: @usr Well, if you don't explain how to improve the situation, it *is* mean. I try to avoid bein mean; rude, maybe, but not mean.

Comment: @n.m. all true. But often, a stern and decisive tone is (wrongly) perceived as rude or mean. Maybe a cultural problem, maybe a character problem. Anyway, the team decided they wanted to lower the rate of such misunderstandings.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
if (stat(argv[1], &sf) == 0 ) {
```

into

```
if (statfs(argv[1], &sf) == 0 ) {
```

and you should be fine.

As commented by n.m., please use compiler option `-Wall` for early detection of nasty mistakes.